# Android - Rotate Object along Y-Axis

Tags: android, android-animation

I've a **TextView** in my app and I want it to rotate from left edge along Y-Axis.

Using this code,

```
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:toDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="2000" />
```

I'm able to make it rotate along the left edge, but it does not move along Y-Axis.

However, when I use **objectAnimator**, it does move along Y-Axis using its **rotationY** property, but then, I cannot set the values **pivotX** and **pivotY** which makes it to rotate along the centre rather than from the left edge.

How do I achieve both the things at the same time?

Please help me!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

check this [card flip animation](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) from android.
basicly you define 4 animations and set the animation order with

```
    getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(
                R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
                R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out)
        .replace(R.id.container, new CardBackFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

you might want to change the angles and "valueFrom", "valueTo" properties to fit your needs.

Comment: there is a difference between transition animation and view rotation

Comment: @grytrn for fragment also there is some issue with card flip animation given by google developers. Only entry rotation for upcoming fragment plays while the exit animation of current fragment doesn't start. It simply makes current fragment invisible and plays for entry fragment only.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate view from left edge, try using the following property of view.

```
android:transformPivotX = "0dp"
```

This will rorate your view from left edge.

Comment: The rotation will be in XY plane, that's not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You can use setRotationY() method to ratate around the y axis.

```
ValueAnimator lockAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);     // value from 0 to 1
lockAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
lockAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator pAnimation) {
        float value = (Float) (pAnimation.getAnimatedValue());
        textView.setRotationY(180 * value);
    }
});
```